# How to Profile Status bar in php (just like linkedin status bar)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

How can I develop Profile progress bar on completing profile, which is same as linkedin, through Php. And user completes his/her profile, the status percent(% increases).

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this a question or a show me how?  Have you Googled it? do you have a Start on it?

Comment: Seems to me that it's a pretty simple calculation to figure out the percent completed, then generating an image to reflect that. Which of these steps do you need help with?

Comment: show me. Yes I searched in google but not got proper function.

Comment: @Rishabh please tell us *your* thoughts on how this should work.

Comment: In my opinion, I have 3 edit profile menu like basic info, education info and address info. on particular menu update than progress bar increase. For eg i put 30% on basic info than on complete basic info progreebar increased 30%

Comment: @Malione maybe not how, but at least the basics. There are people that need the ideea.

Answer (score 7):

For a progress bar to work you have to specify some criteria.
For example, on SO, if you go to [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) you will have on you profile a `completeness report`.

Every part of the `completeness report` has certain points or a certain percentage of total amount of points you can earn.

Based on your `User Profile` criteria you can make that progress bar.

For example:

```
$hasCompletedSkill = 10;
$hasCompletedBooks = 15;
$maximumPoints  = 100;
$percentage = ($hasCompletedSkill+$hasCompletedBooks)*$maximumPoints/100;

echo "
    <div style='width:100px; background-color:white; height:30px; border:1px solid #000;'>
    <div style='width:".$percentage."px; background-color:red; height:30px;'></div>
</div>";
```

It will output:

[image: Percent completed]