# How to add profile completeness progress bar in PHP and WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

How to show the profile completeness progress bar in php WordPress? After registration, I am displaying the whole values in the user profile page. Depending on the data filled in on the edit profile page, I want to show the progress bar on the profile page. Is there any way to do this?

```php
if ($firstname != "") {
    // add some points and show status bar is 2%
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'the' profile completeness progress bar?

Comment: for adding a progress bar, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190898/progress-bar-with-html-and-css/18631308#18631308

Comment: filling up on the edit profile page need to show the progress bar, like your profile completed 50% please fill the all fields you will get a new privilege like this.

Comment: @Daniel , But depends up on the value filled in the edit profile page, i need to show the progress bar in the profile page. is that possible with this above link

Comment: you'll need to add functionality to Wordpress to calculate a percentage of completeness. First try it yourself and post the problems you encounter along the way, then we can help you with that.

Comment: I am stuck. From where i can start? any idea?

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142690/percent-complete-bar-for-profile-similar-linkedin  Thanks Mihai Iorga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$maximumPoints  = 100;
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {                 
             if($twitterHandle!=""){
                $hasCompletedTwitterHandle = 10;

             }
             if($linkedinHandle!=""){
                $hasCompletedLinkedinHandle = 10;

             }
             if($googleplusHandle!=""){
                $hasCompletedGoogleplusHandle = 10;

             }
             if($website_url!=""){
                $hasCompletedWebsite_url = 10;

             }

             $percentage = ($hasCompletedTwitterHandle+$hasCompletedLinkedinHandle+$hasCompletedGoogleplusHandle+$hasCompletedWebsite_url)*$maximumPoints/100;
             echo "Your percentage of profile completenes is".$percentage."%";
             echo "<div style='width:100px; background-color:white; height:30px; border:1px solid #000;'>
             <div style='width:".$percentage."px; background-color:red; height:30px;'></div></div>";
        }
```

i have did this code now the progress bar is coming. i have an issue with this code, if a user is logged in he can see the other users profile progress bar. i do not need this, how can i restrict that, if a user is logged in that user want to see his progress bar only

Comment: get current logged in userId and get displayed user id and if both are equal then display that bar..keep it simple !!

Comment: Yes did it $current_login_user_id = get_current_user_id();

Answer (score 1):

i think css could do the trick....

```
   <div style="background:red;border:1px solid;">
        <div style="width:<?=$completePercentage?>%;background:green;">
            <?=$completePercentage?>    
        </div>
   </div>
```

you can calculate value for "$completePercentage" var based on your profile completeness criteria !!